# installing pyo on mac os X 10.10.2

Tags: python-2.7, osx-yosemite, pyo

i recently installed pyo following this guide: [Downloading](http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/pyodoc/download.html) and [Compiling](http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/pyodoc/compiling.html). Then i tried `import pyo` on python but this appeared

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pyo
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyo.py", line 21, in <module>
    import pyolib.analysis as analysis
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyolib/analysis.py", line 30, in <module>
    from _core import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyolib/_core.py", line 32, in <module>
    from _pyo import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pyo.so, 2): Symbol not found: _Pm_Close
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pyo.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

What can i do? I'm a beginner, if you need other info just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution: use installer, nothing else. Still, i don't know why it doesn't work any other way.